# Insert multi arrays to database

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have multi arrays:

Array
(

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://213b572-ba681bf9cc9e
        [1] => http://f057-4139-ac40-bc4449722ffc
        [2] => http://b-c151-4ba1-b7b7-842771c36d6b
        [3] => http://5a77fb-8fce-4793-868f-c9fd73524037
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://8-d832-4b34-a55b-da04ad8cdd09
        [1] => http://b38-6a60-4233-b207-f40fae2ef431
        [2] => http://3-f31c-49c4-87ee-fcada05a105f
        [3] => http://07514-e438-45e2-906e-b440cbcbf8dc
    )

......

[76] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://8-d832-4b34-a55b-da04ad8cdd09
        [1] => http://b38-6a60-4233-b207-f40fae2ef431
        [2] => http://3-f31c-49c4-87ee-fcada05a105f
        [3] => http://07514-e438-45e2-906e-b440cbcbf8dc
    )
```

I want my database are:

```
          | id | id_page | url |

          | 1    | 1       | http://jjjjjjjjj |

          | 2    | 1       | http://jjjjjjjjj|  

          ......

          | 1000 | 76      | http://jjjjjjjjj|
```

I use:

```
foreach ($hrefs as $key => $href) {
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO urls(`id`, `id_page`, `url`) VALUES ('', '$key', '$href')");
}
```

But not working.

@:Aleksandr Mochalygin

mysqli_connect.php

```
`$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "vlbd");
mysqli_query($con, "set names 'utf8'");
//Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}`
```

Function query:

```
function insertUrlsToDb() {
global $con;

$pages = getPagesFromDb(); // pages array to database (limit 4 pages)
$hrefs = getHrefByPages($pages); // hrefs multidimentions array 

foreach ($hrefs as  $href) {
    foreach ($href as $key => $value) {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO urls(`id`, `id_page`, `url`)
                    VALUES ('', '$key', '$value')");
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
}`
```

$pages is array into database (limit 4 pages)
$hrefs is multidimentions array like above.

Comment: Did you look at the [errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 level array, so you need to use `foreach` twice:

```
foreach ($hrefs as $idPage => $arrayHrefs) {
    foreach ($arrayHrefs as $href) {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO urls(id,id_page,url) VALUES ('', '$idPage', '$href')");
    }
}
```

Comment: I follow you and get errors: **Couldn't fetch mysqli in file.php on line 159**. My code: `foreach ($hrefs as  $href) {
  foreach ($href as $key => $value) {
   mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO     urls(`id`, `id_page`, `url`)
      VALUES ('',     '$key', '$value')");
  }`

Comment: Show the whole code, pls. It seems what you have an error during your mysqli connection

Comment: @TriMinh How many times do you call this function? The code `mysqli_close($con);` closes mysqli-connection, so, if you call function 2nd time -- the connection will be already closed.

Comment: @TriMinh, it seems to me, what you need to teach basic PHP, especially about arrays. I change code, as I understand your problem -- so check it now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i use loop:

```
foreach ($hrefs as  $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO urls(`id`, `id_page`, `url`)
                            VALUES('', '$key', '$value1')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    }
}
```

Problem is resolved. Thank's you!